# Implementation of Vector in C++

Tags: c++, iterator, vectors

This is a simple implementation of vector in C++. Please offer your reviews to improve the code.

```
#ifndef VECTOR_HPP
#define VECTOR_HPP

template <typename T> class vector{
    int size;//size allocated on the memory
    int index;//current number of elements
    T* arr;
    void resize(){
        T* temp = new T[size];
        for (int i = 0; i <index ; ++i) {
            temp[i] = arr[i];
        }
        delete[] arr;

        T* arr = new T[size*2];
        for (int i = 0; i < index ; ++i) {
           arr[i] = temp[i];
        }
        size = size*2;
        delete[] temp;

    }
public:
    vector(){
        size = 50;
        index = 0;
        T* arr = new T[size];
    }
    vector(int sz){
        size = sz;
        index = 0;
        T* arr = new T[size];

    }
    ~vector(){
        delete[] arr;
    }

    typedef T* iterator;

    iterator begin(){
        return arr;
    }

    iterator end(){
        return arr + index;
    }

    T* front(){
        return arr[0];
    }

    T* back(){
        return arr[index];
    }
    void push_back(const T& t){
        if((size - index) == 1){
            resize();

        }
        arr[index+1] = t;
        index++;

    }
    void pop_back(){
        index--;
    }

    void insert(iterator pos, const T& t){
        if((size -index) < 1) resize();
        int npos = pos - arr;
        for (int i = index; i > npos ; i--) {
            arr[i+1] = arr[i];
        }
        arr[npos] = t;
        index++;

    }

    void erase(iterator pos){
        int npos = arr - pos;
        if((size - index) < 1) resize();
        for (int i = npos; i <index-1 ; ++i) {
            arr[i] = arr[i+1];
        }
        index--;

    }

    T& operator[](int){

    }

    int length(){
        return index;
    }
    bool empty(){
        return index == 0;
    }


};

#endif //VECTOR_HPP
```

Comment: This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. See also [this meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/code-should-include-a-description-of-what-the-code-does).

Comment: There are also some broken parts (does index mean the index of the last element of the number of elements in the array, the code can't seem to decide)

Answer (score 7):

There are three severe errors in your code:

**Rule of Three/Five/Zero**

[This](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) is an invaluable resource. Anytime you write a user-defined destructor, you will need to write the copy constructor and assignment. You lack the copy constructor or assignment, so the compiler will happily provide one for you, and that one will not do the right thing:

```
vector<int> v;        // we have an array of size zero with capacity 50
vector<int> v2 = v;   // we do not have two arrays: both vectors have
                      // the SAME pointer
// <== v2 gets destroyed, we run delete [] array
// <== v gets destroyed, we run delete [] array again! boom
```

In addition to the double free, you get the other issue in that the user might expect a deep copy but actually `v2` is basically just a Java-style reference to `v`. Fixing this is an absolute must.

**Resizing**

This is definitely non-functional. You delete your member `arr`, then, separately from that, you create a locally scoped array `arr` that you write stuff into. At the end of `resize()`, the `vector` object will have a deleted local array!

The correct way to `resize()` is to allocate a new array (only have to do one!) of double the size, to copy/move from your member into the new array, and then simply change your member to point to the new array. This should be **one** allocation (of the doubled array) and **one** deletion (of the old array).

**Off-by-one**

The first `push_back()` writes into `arr[1]`. What goes into `arr[0]`?

---

Once you fix those, there are other issues with your code:

**Limits on Types**

When you construct like this:

```
vector(){
    size = 50;
    index = 0;
    T* arr = new T[size];
}
```

You are adding a restriction on `T`. Namely, that it must be default constructible:

```
struct X { X(int ) { } };
vector<X> v;
```

leads to:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'vector<T>::vector() [with T = X]':
main.cpp:108:15:   required from here
main.cpp:26:28: error: no matching function for call to 'X::X()'
         T* arr = new T[size];
                            ^
```

The way to avoid this is to use global `::operator new` to allocate memory without constructing any objects.

**Naming**

You have member variables named `size`, which is actually the capacity of the vector, and `index`, which is its size. Those names are confusing and should be changed to reflect their actual purpose.

**Object Destruction**

A `vector` owns its objects. When you `pop` or `erase` from a vector, it must release ownership - which will involve explicitly calling the destructor on your type. You do not currently do this.

**Resizing, part 2**

Resizing should **only** happen on insertion. You also do it on `erase()`. This is illogical. Why would removing an element lead to doubling in the array size?

**operator[]**

Where's the body?

**const overloads**

If I have a `const vector<int>`, I cannot do anything with it. That's not useful. `empty()` and `length()` (which should be spelled `size()`) can just be `const` member functions. There also need to be `const` overloads for `begin()`, `end()`, `operator[]`, `front()`, and `back()`.

Comment: Good review, and now I also voted.

Comment: I'm a little new to codereview, do you want me to update my code with your suggestions. Is that how it works.

Comment: @Antithesis No, never change code in a question (unless it was originally mis-copied, etc). If you want to update your code, you can create a followup question.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the standard containers, they have both a capacity and a size.
A container has reserved space for capacity elements, but only contains size ones. The rest of the space is unused, no object is constructed there.

In contrast, your container constructs elements on allocating space.

<sub>I'm blaming Barry for only leaving so little else to say.</sub>